# What is the density of a homogeneous disk with mass $m$ and radius $a$?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, physics

Could someone help me understand why the density of a homogeneous disk is $\dfrac{m}{(\pi a)^2}$?

I am trying to understand an example about finding the moment of inertia of an object.

The question is : Find the moments of inertia with respect to the -axis, the -axis, and
the origin of a thin homogeneous disk of mass and radius , centered at the origin.

And the example starts with this: Since the disk is homogeneous, its density is constant and given by $$r(x, y)=\frac{m}{(\pi a)^2}$$.

Well, I really don't understand why  the density is $\frac{m}{(\pi a)^2}$. Coulde someone help me with this?

Comment: The mass is $m$, the area is $\pi a^2$, so the mass per unit area (density) is $\frac{m}{\pi a^2}$.  We are considering area rather than volume, since we are dealing with a lamina (a plate of negligible thickness).

Comment: Nicee. Thanks a lot for the fast reply!

Comment: Seems there is a mistake on the textbook, because pi*a^2 makes more sence than (pi*a)^2. Thanks you again :D

Comment: I did not even "see" the $(\pi a)^2$, which of course is a typo.